# winsock reset after connection established

Tags: tcp, winsock

I got a problem about WinSock. The situation as follow:

In LAN, different subnet, Server listen on port using non-blocking socket, 1000 clients connect to Server, also non-blocking. Network packet capture show nearly all connection is established, but Server reset the connection before accept() invoked in several milliseconds after three-way handshake finished. This issue appears in larger amount of clients only, when I reduce the client count to 100, no reset.

Is there any reason connection reset occurred after connection established without any other further operations?

NOTE: I google this issue already, but no help. And, of course, SO_LINGER is not used in Server. Even if SO_LINGER is used in Server, but accept() is not invoked yet, it makes no sense!

It takes me two days, so you couldn't image how grateful if your advice help me out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What have you configured the listen backlog to be on the listening socket?

It's most likely too low.

Is is REALLY realistic to test for 1000 concurrent connection attempts?

I talk about setting realistic goals for server connection testing here on my blog: http://www.serverframework.com/asynchronousevents/2010/10/how-to-support-10000-or-more-concurrent-tcp-connections---part-2---perf-tests-from-day-0.html

Comment: thanks for your advice, but I'm some sort of confused.

I configure the backlog to 1000, is it too large, so API truncate the value to maximum queue length(several hundred)?

And also, MSDN says "If a connection request arrives and the queue is full, the client will receive an error with an indication of WSAECONNREFUSED." I guess this means the new connection won't successful, but, in my application, connection reset just after three-way handshake finished.

Thanks again

Comment: Yes, you're more likely to get a connection refused. You may simply be failing to deal with the new connections in some way? Also, what networking hardware do you have between your clients and your server?

Comment: It's my company, I don't know what hardware exactly. Server is run at Windows 2003 Server system, is this affected tcp connections? I mean, is there any limits about the OS cause this issue?

Comment: oh, maybe gateway, client and server is in different subnets

Comment: It might be the router. If you run WireShark on the server machine AND the client machine what do you see? Does the client machine send the RST or does it only show on the server machine's WireShark log?

Comment: WinreShark run on the client, it shows client receive the RST from Server, after client sends last ACK of three-way handshake several milliseconds later.

I've had talks with my colleagues, they told me that the gateway doesn't configured to RESET frequently TCP connections, so I guess maybe the router doesn't have an influence on the issue

Comment: Do you see the RST on the server machine's wireshark log?

Comment: sorry, a little busy yesterday. hmm, yes, server also RST. I wonder maybe it's the server machine limits the connections per seconds, is that possible?

Comment: Only if your listen backlog and accept processing speed isn't fast enough, but I'd expect you to get WSAECONNREFUSED rather than RST.

Comment: Just in case that you want to know, it turns out that you are right! The reason is my accept() too slow, so listen() backlog is exceeded. The server machine is run windows 2003 SP2, so it has a SYN attack protection enabled, and this protection cause undocumented behavior on WinSock, you can see it here: http://www.tech-archive.net/Archive/Development/microsoft.public.win32.programmer.networks/2005-10/msg00313.html